# I have visual studio 2013 update 1 but I can not see MVC 5 project template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have visual studio 2013 update 1 but I can not see MVC 5 project template?
Is it necessary to install additional package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS2013, all web projects are created by choosing the `ASP.NET Web Application` template from the "New Project" dialog. There aren't separate templates for all of the different combinations any longer.

See [Creating ASP.NET Web Projects in Visual Studio 2013](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Take a ASP.NET Web Application Project --> MVC Template or Empty. Make sure to check MVC check box

Right click on your project in solution explorer--> Add new item --> Select MVC5 --> Click add